Getting blank pdf when sending data back to the client
I have a two-hop system in which a client (browser or Postman) makes a request to a server, which then makes a second request for a PDF to be served back to the original client.
This ExpressJS code works just fine (the downloaded PDF is viewable) when I make an HTTP GET:
app.get('/download-test', async (_req, res) => {

  const fetchResponse = await fetch('https://link.testfile.org/PDF10MB');
  if (fetchResponse.ok) {

    const blob = await fetchResponse.blob();
    const buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
    res.status(200);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="test.pdf"');
    res.end(Buffer.from(buffer));
  } else {
    res.status(404).send('Not found');
  }
});

But when I implement this IRL in my application's server code, I get a blank PDF back that is 40k larger than the byte array/buffers (which have the correct file size - confirmed via logging). Based on some Internet sleuthing, I have seen examples where Buffer.from requires an encoding, but my test code doesn't have this, and it works just fine.
Does anyone have any thoughts about what's going on and what I can do to fix it?

Try avoid using blob and arrayBuffer, and just use streams for server-side envs (especially since you operate with larger files). This may avoid your buffer-related issues.
try {
    const fetchResponse = await fetch('https://link.testfile.org/PDF10MB');

    if (fetchResponse.ok) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="test.pdf"');
      
        // Stream res directly
        fetchResponse.body.pipe(res);
    } else {
        res.status(404).send('Not found');
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching or processing the PDF:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
}


This works fine in my test code but not in my actual application. Once I got the typings figured out for .pipe, it doesn't return the PDF at all and instead returns the body prop defined by ts-rest.

Two updates on this:


there are extra bytes being added to my PDF due to something involving UTF-8 encoding (which is not happening in the first fetch call), and


I tried calling response.body.setEncoding('binary') before the .pipe call and that actually breaks the download in that it breaks the PDF download.



@icfantv Not sure what your up to now, but perhaps check for any interference from middleware?

It turns out that serverless-express' default configuration does not include application/pdf as a supported binary file. Rather, it only includes images. It took an insane amount of digging, but once we added application/pdf to binarySettings.contentTypes (in the config object passed to serverlessExpress(...) it worked fine.  Ironically, it works fine out of the box with just plain ExpressJS.  :shrug:
